# Picture of the first homology group

Tags: reference-request

I have to draw a picture of the base of the first homology group over $\mathbb{Z}$ of $C$, where $C$ is a compact Riemann surface of positive genus.
How can i draw it?
Is there some free programm wich can do it?
Or do you know some site where i can find the picture?

Comment: i put this question with this tag but i'm not sure that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for example Figure $3.1$ [here](http://wstein.org/books/modform/modform/weight_two.html), for the case of genus $g=3$. Can you generalize this for arbitrary genus $g\ge 1$ ? In general we have $H_1(M,\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$, for a compact Riemannian surface $M$ of genus $g$.

The homology is generated by the homology classes of loops going around each of the $g$ holes of $M$ together with
the homology classes of loops transverse to these, going around each of
the handles. So we have $2g$ loops.

Comment: yes but the problem is to draw the direct sum of g torus to rappresent my Riwmann surface. How can i picture it? i don't if there is a standard way to rappresent the direc sum of g torus

Comment: The connected sum of $g$ tori, see Figure $3.1$.